# M2 - Have client be able to edit/change header on each CMS Page?

Tags: magento2, css, cms-pages

I have a client that wants to be able to change the header themselves through the admin (with css) so it can be different on each CMS page.

They want this because their current header is transparent, and on some pages with dark backgrounds/light backgrounds it looks odd. *So basically they want to control it.*

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would achieve this?

I know I can use `< style > OVERIDE HEADER CSS< / style >` directly in the CMS page, is that the best practice though?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You want to add the custom css for a specific cms page?

Comment: Read more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4454